# How to skip setting UIApplication.applicationIconBadgeNumber when local notification received in foreground?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I scheduled `UILocalNotification` which set up application badge number to 1.

But I don't want to set up application badge number if application is in foreground.
To achieve this I tried the following code in `AppDelegate`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:
        (UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

It looks like at first the code above called and only after it badge number from notification is obtained and setting up.
As a result the code above has no effect.

**How *not* to set up badge number when local notification is received when application in foreground?**

Workaround can be implemented, e.g. clear badge number when application is about to background, but I am curious if there is cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want different operation for foreground and background, then you need to do the housekeeping on this front. Register listeners for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` and `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notifications (or similar ones along the activation/deactivation path). But this is still not a stable solution as it highly depends on when the handlers are called and when the notificaiton is posted.

For a clean solution you should **clear the badge when the app enters background, as you suggested**. This is in correspondence with the behavior of other applications. IMHO it does not worth the hassle to complicate the operation, it is very easy to introduce bugs in this way.

Comment: Thanks @allrpog for clarification. To be sure I also cleared badge on application launch, but UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification more suitable here. In fact I just want to have a badge before user open application and not forget to react on it. If user is opened badge I consider that notification via badge number is not required anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is set “at the same time” as the delegate method is being called, instead of before or after, since setting a breakpoint in the delegate method seems to update the badge to the number you pretend.

So, first (ugly) solution:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 125*NSEC_PER_MSEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 333;
    });
}
```

(125ms seems to do the trick).

The second solution I though did not work out. Since `applicationIconBadgeNumber` is `readwrite` for `UILocalNotification` I tried to modify that on the fly… but it didn’t work.

The third solution seems to work, and seems to be clear enough.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [application cancelLocalNotification:notification];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 333;
}
```

(I will recommend checking the `application.applicationState` before doing that, though)

The final solution is what you comment in your last paragraph: simply set the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` in `applicationWillResignActive:` to the correct value. As far as I can see, the badge number cannot be seen while the app is in foreground.

Comment: [application cancelLocalNotification:notification]; seems works, but after calling this line and reruning app with the line commented, badge cleared - application behaviour looks unstable - IMHO this is because notification cancelled after already fired - not sure though... Anyway thanks for description different approaches

Comment: I didn’t see the same instability after canceling, at least in the simulator. But my test app didn’t do much else.

Comment: I tried on iPhone 4s. It is also reproduced from time to time, not always - I avoid such instability, because it is difficult to reproduce and fix later. I don't know what exactly is wrong but since there is more robust solution, I prefer it, althought solution in your answer looks more suitable

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

(means "do not show badge".)

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

means "do nothing".

Comment: Is it documented by Apple?

Comment: Not what Apple says- 

"The default value of this property is 0, which means that no badge is displayed"

Comment: And yet... you seem to be right! 

When I send 0 nothing changes, when I send -1 it gets cleared.